# How can I setup this Exlusion Request URI filter in Google Analytics?

Tags: filter, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

**I want to exclude all the URLs that have  "PhoneNumber">**

example: /meny.no/Om-MENY/Bli-medlem/?PhoneNumber=90256457

I tried in Admin in Google Analytics Filter:

Custom

Exclude

Request URI

Filter Pattern: ~/meny.no/Om-MENY/Bli-medlem/?PhoneNumber

and

^~/meny.no/Om-MENY/Bli-medlem/?PhoneNumber

But they dont work.

Comment: You're probably better off by just excluding the query parameter `PhoneNumber` instead, which can be done in the View Settings. This leaves the rest of your URL (and therefore your pageview count) intact.

Comment: Hi, i think I found a solution:
^/meny\.no/Om-MENY/Bli-medlem/\?PhoneNumber.*